# e.target.value gives me this error whenever i enter more than one letter react Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update my useState value with the one in  so I am using 
`setObject(prev => ({...prev, MachineName: e.target.value }));`
but whenever i enter more than a letter i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' 
of null"

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
   MachineName: "",
   Building: "",
   IP: ""
});

const actionHandler = () => {
  //setObject({ MachineName: " ", Building: " ", IP: " " });
};
function UpdateValue(e) {
    setObject(prev => ({ ...prev, MachineName: e.target.value }));
    console.log("Test", object.MachineName);
}
return (
  <Modal
    show={true}
    size="lg"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>New Machine</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <Form>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <FloatingLabelInput
            id="1"
            className="FormFields"
            label="Machine Name"
            value={object.MachineName}
            onInput={e => UpdateValue(e)}
          />
        </Col>

      </Row>


    </Form>
  </Modal.Body>

</Modal>
);
```

Comment: ...(e.target.value ? MachineName: e.target.value : {}) try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to give some default values, and maybe bind the envirement(with arrow function) like this:

```
const UpdateValue = e => {
  const { target = {} } = e || {};
  const { value = "" } = target || {};
  setObject(prev => ({ ...prev, MachineName: value }));
  console.log("Test", object.MachineName);
}
```

Comment: The bind envirement should happen down under in your current code, `onInput={e => UpdateValue(e)}` but you can also do it like this with arrow function: `onInput={UpdateValue}`